# Intellisense issue in vscode with typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, parcel

I have a typescript project that I edit via VSCode.

I'm using parcel, which means I have to "import" images into code. By default, typescript doesn't like that, so I've added a `declarations.d.ts` file in my repository to allow these.

For some reason, VSCode only considers the declarations file when it's open in the editor. As soon as I close the file, these errors pop up again:

> Cannot find module [...] or its corresponding type declarations ts(2307)

Here is a [minimal reproductible example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vJeJTQqRdoukzZQ3llFjSUobys8CtJ7R/view?usp=drive_link), as well as a [screen recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1up44Xa2oaNgwsdAxsgv0WA-MsywGTsjP/view?usp=drive_link) of the issue

```
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── src
    ├── assets
    │   └── image.png
    ├── declarations.d.ts
    ├── index.html
    └── main.ts
```

### Stuff I tried

- restart typescript server
- quit and relaunch vscode
- reboot computer
- reset vscode settings
- update vscode
- clean reinstall vscode (including extensions and settigns)

### Setup

- **OS**: Debian
- **VScode**: 1.83.1 x64, installed from .deb with apt
- **Extensions**: none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this config file in your codebase as **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "lib": ["ES6","DOM"]
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "include": ["./src/**/*", "tests/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "tests"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to use a tsconfig file, but everything I tried was breaking some other thing compared to the default one...
I had to add "resolveJsonModule" to your config (which was not working properly in my tests), but apart from that, it worked perfectly. Thanks!